# Wrong output value of Legacy Code Tool's Sfunction

Tags: matlab, simulink

[image]

I am getting wrong result of the example published in the Mathworks documentation in the [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/integrating-existing-c-functions-into-simulink-models-with-the-legacy-code-tool.html)

I am expecting the output to be 2 times the sine wave of amplitude 1, but I am getting constant value of large magnitude in the order of 1e8.

I used the following commands:

```
def = legacy_code('initialize');
def.HeaderFiles = {'myfunc.h'};%,'mat.h'};
def.SourceFiles = {'myfunc.c'};
def.SFunctionName = 'sfun_myfunc';
def.OutputFcnSpec = 'double y1 = myfunc(double u1)';
def.Options.singleCPPMexFile = false;
legacy_code('sfcn_cmex_generate', def);
legacy_code('sfcn_tlc_generate', def);
legacy_code('compile', def);
legacy_code('slblock_generate', def);
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the header file, instead of using #ifndef I used erroneously #ifdef.